# Navigation bar size changes whenever going from one HTML to another HTML

Tags: html, css, navigation, size

I'm creating my personal website but having trouble understanding why navigation bar size changes when I change from one HTML file to another HTML file. For example, when I click Photography_Color HTML, the navigation bar becomes bigger compared to the Main HTML. All the HTML files are using the same CSS, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">
    <!--SOCIAL MEDIA ICON STYLESHEET-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>J[a]Son | Art & Code </title>
    <div class="top">
        <div class = "center">
          <h><a href="home.html">J[a]son</a></h>
          <p>Personal Blog</p>
        </div>
        <nav class = "top_child">
          <div class = "logos">
            <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" class="fa fa-github"></a>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
          </div>
          <div class = "nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="photography_1">
                  <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                  <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="coding.html">CODING</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
}

html, body {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    z-index: 100;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.center a{
    color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.center a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.photography_1 {
    display: none;
}

.photography_1 li a {
    /*display: block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: rgb(221, 215, 215);
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: perhaps where the tag was not closed

Comment: you have some formatting issues here. a navigation abr does not belong into a head section.

Comment: ...and why is your <div class = "top"></div> inside the head tag

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your div with the class of top, out of the  tag and inside a  tag.

The  element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the  tag and the  tag.

The  tag defines the document's body. It contains all the contents of an HTML document, such as headings, paragraphs, images, hyperlinks, tables, lists, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top">
    <!-- Put the rest of whats inside the top div here -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```